# Magento2 Checkout Total Title

Tags: magento2.2.3, grand-total, order-totals

I'm trying to change **Grand Total** label in Checkout page using following code but it's not working

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test Order Total</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

any idea? what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it by below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test Order Total</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```